# MIT app inventor rest returns error when running on tablet

Tags: android, rest, tablet

I created an app in MIT App Inventor witch sends a rest post command to google app script.
it works great on phone, but when I run it on a tablet it doesn't work properly, instead, it says "your client has issued a malformed or illegal request".

I cannot understand the problem seeing as both requests are to the same URL and the body is the same.

is there a difference between phone and app?